# do Carmo Differential forms and application Chapter 2 Exercise 6

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Line integrals are quite useful in the study of complex functions $f:\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$. Here the complex plane $\Bbb C$ is identified with $\Bbb R^2$ by setting $z=x+iy$, $z\in\Bbb C$, $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$. It is convenient to introduce the complex differential form $dz = dx+idy$ and to write
> $$ f(z) =u(x,y)+iv(x,y) = u+iv.$$
> Then the complex form
> $$f(z)dz = (u+iv)(dx+idy) = (udx-vdy)+i(udy+vdx)$$
> has $udx-vdy$ as its real part and $udy+vdx$ as its imaginary part. Define
> $$\int_c f(z) dz = \int_c(udx-vdy)+i\int_c(udy+vdx)$$
> Assume that $u,v\in C^1$. Recall that $f$ is holomorphic if and only if $u_x = v_y, u_y = -v_x$

Question. If $f$ is holomorphic, the function $f'(z)$ (the derivative of $f$ in $z$) given by the equation $df:=du+idv = f'(z)dz$ is well defined and $f'(z) = u_x-iu_y$.

In the question I what should I check for well definedness?

Comment: You should check that, writing $\mathrm{d}f = \alpha \mathrm{d}z + \beta \mathrm{d}\overline{z}$, then $\beta = 0$ (where $\mathrm{d}\overline{z} = \mathrm{d}x - i\mathrm{d}y$): it follows that $\mathrm{d}f = \alpha \mathrm{d}z$ and thus, one can define $"\mathrm{d}f/\mathrm{d}z" = f'(z)$.

Comment: @Didier Thankyou for your commnet. But in the problem $df$ is 'defined' as $du+idv$ and also, as far as I know we write $df=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dx^i$ for real valued function. In this case, $f$ is vector valued.

Comment: And the problem also ask to show $f'(z) = u_x-iu_y$ so I think I need to show writing $df =\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}du+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}dv = du+idv$. And from this, deduce $f'(z)$. what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete answer. Write $f(x,y) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$. Then $u$ and $v$ are real valued function and:
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}f &= \mathrm{d}u + i \mathrm{d}v & \text{by Do Carmo's definition } (":=")\\
&= \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}y\right) + i \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}y \right) & \text{by definition of partial derivatives}
\end{align}
Suppose now that $f$ is holomorphic, that is, according to Do Carmo, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. Then the last equality becomes:
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}f &= \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}y \right) + i \left(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}x + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}y  \right) \\
&=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right) \mathrm{d}x + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + i \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right) \mathrm{d}x + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right) i\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right) \left(\mathrm{d}x + i \mathrm{d}y\right) \\
&= \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \right) \mathrm{d}z &\text{by definition of } \mathrm{d}z 
\end{align}
Hence, writing $x+iy = z$ and defining $f'(z) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, it follows that if $f$ is holomorphic, one can write $\mathrm{d}f = f'(z)\mathrm{d}z$.

Hence, if $f$ is holomorphic, the function $f'$ is **uniquely** determined by the relation $\mathrm{d}f = f'(z)\mathrm{d}z$: this is what is implicitly suggested by "well defined" I guess.

Comment: Well defined means uniquely defined by the relation $\mathrm{d}f = f'(z) \mathrm{d}z$.

Comment: I finally figured out what you meant. Thanks.